# Click Delete link for each duplicate href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, I have some divs with `<a>` tags, each containing a href of `/User.aspx?ID=[some ID]`. I wish to click the `Delete <a>` tag under the parent of the parent of the parent of any divs with duplicate ID's in the href.

Here is my code:

```
var z = 0;
var info = {};
$("a:contains('Delete')").each(function() { 
    z++;
    var x = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("span.UserLink a").attr("href");
    var id = x.replace("/User.aspx?ID=", "");
    info[z] = id;
    console.log(info[z]);

});
var uniqueIds = {};
$.each(info, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueIds) === -1) { uniqueIds.push(el) }
    else { $("html").find("span.UserLink a[href='/User.aspx?ID='"+info[i]+"']").parent().parent().parent().find("a:contains('Delete')").click() }
});
```

Comment: Could you add a sample html that you wish to manipulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use arrays, not objects

Maybe just a typo, I think you wanted to use arrays for `info` and `uniqueIds`

```
var info = [];
var uniqueIds = [];
```

#### jQuery.each already provides an index

You don't need `z`

```
$("a:contains('Delete')").each(function(index) {
    var x = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("span.UserLink a").attr("href");
    var id = x.replace("/User.aspx?ID=", "");
    info[index] = id;
    console.log(info[z]);
});
```

#### Use meaningful names

`x` and `info` aren't very good names, you could try (for example) `userLinkHref` and `foundIds`

#### You could store the delete button in the first loop and use it in the second loop

```
var foundDeleteLinks = [];
$("a:contains('Delete')").each(function() {
    var $deleteLink = $(this);
    var userLinkHref = $deleteLink.parent().parent().parent().find("span.UserLink a").attr("href");
    var id = userLinkHref.replace("/User.aspx?ID=", "");
    foundDeleteLinks.push({id:id,$deleteLink:$deleteLink});
    console.log(id);
});
var uniqueIds = [];
$.each(foundDeleteLinks, function(i, deleteLink){
    var id = deleteLink.id;
    if($.inArray(id, uniqueIds) === -1) { uniqueIds.push(id) }
    else {
        deleteLink.$deleteLink.click();
    }
});
```

#### You may be able to do it in one loop

```
var foundIds = [];
$("a:contains('Delete')").each(function() {
    var $deleteLink = $(this);
    var userLinkHref = $deleteLink.parent().parent().parent().find("span.UserLink a").attr("href");
    var id = userLinkHref.replace("/User.aspx?ID=", "");
    if($.inArray(id, foundIds) === -1) { foundIds.push(id) }
    else { $deleteLink.click(); }
});
```

---

I hope that helps enough to find your problems.